# Facing issue while import pycountry package in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, python-import, jupyter-notebook

I have installed pycountry using my terminal with the below command

```
pip install pycountry
```

Installed successfully but it shows error when I try to import in jupyter notebook while I can import it from the terminal:

[image: Import failure in the Jupyter notebook]

Here you can see that I have it installed from the terminal:

[image: Picture showing that the package is installed in the python2.7 interpreter.]

**System Details:**

- System: Mac osx
- Jupyter Notebook
- python version 2.7

Comment: May be you installed it in your default python, which is not in accessable from ipython notebook.

Comment: When you open the Jupyter Notebook which version of python does it show? I believe you have more than one python interpreter on your computer and while you have installed the package for one of them jupyter is being launched using an other one.

Comment: Thank for your response AhsanulHaque and @Bakuri.I have checked the verison and packages installed via jupyter notebook using '!python -V', '!pip freeze' it shows python version has 2.7.12 and list of packages installed where pycountry package is included in the list.

Comment: **Issue fixed**: Used the below script to identify the installed packages and pycountry is not their in the list                                                                            <!-- language: Python -->                                                                              import pip 
for i in pip.get_installed_distributions(local_only=True):
print(i)  and used **import sys**, **sys.path** to identify the package path and paste the copied folder of pycountry in the path and it works now